# binding ngModel from controller in angularJs or calling function from ngModel

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to bind an unknown array index based on some property in angularjs.

```
    <select id="iditemtype" ng-model="method(entity, e)"
        ng-options="e as e.configValue for e in allConfig() | filter:{typeName:'ItemType'}">
    </select>

//javascript method inside controller

    function method()
    {
        var index = -1;
        for(var i=0;i<entity.attributes.length;i++){
            if(entity.attributes[i].type=='ItemType'){
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(index==-1){
            entity.attributes.push(0, e);
        }
        else
            entity.attributes[index] = e;
    }
```

Above sample code is my actual intention. I want to bind specific attribute from a select list.

I am using `angularjs 1.3`

Answer (score 1):

Here you cannot pass a function to ng-model because Angular has to be able to set the value when the user changes the input value. Here you can use $watch to achieve your goal also you can use `ng-change` directive of angular with `select` here. Call function on select value change and set respected variable in controller function which you have bind with ng-change.

Comment: Yeah, Use ng-change here to achieve your goal.You can refer angular docs for that. It's easy.